# What is wrong with my DESKey (BlackBerry API)?

Tags: blackberry, encryption, des

I have an application developed on BlackBerry JE 4.6.1 that decrypts an information from WebServer using DES algorythm. 
If I send encrypted information to the server, it is decrypted well. But in case if the server sends an encrypted data, 
I do not get the correct value after decryption.
Key is supposed to be the same and crypted information is sent base64 encoded.
During debugging I have found out, that after DESKey is created it's inner data differs from the byte array passed to the constructor.
For example if I create the DESKey the next way

```
String keyStr = "2100000A";
DESKey desKey = new DESKey(keyStr.getBytes()); // pass the byte array {'2','1','0','0','0','0','0','A'}
```

the method desKey.getData() returns the byte array {'2','1','1','1','1','1','1','@'} that differs from the initial key bytes.

So is it possible for such behavior of the DESKey to be the reason why I can not decrypt data from server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desKey.getData() behaviour is expected.

The [doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/DESDecryptorEngine.html) states:

> DES operates on 64 bit blocks and has
>   an effective key length of 56 bits. In
>   reality, the key is 64 bits but there
>   are 8 bits of parity used which means
>   that the effective key length is only
>   56 bits. Every eighth bit is used for
>   parity and it is the least significant
>   bit that is used for parity.

Parity bit [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit):

> A parity bit, or check bit, is a bit that is added to ensure that the number of bits with the value one in a set of bits is even or odd. Parity bits are used as the simplest form of error detecting code.

So, this is how it happens:

```
'2' => 0x32 => 00110010 => 0011001 + (parity bit 0) => 00110010 => 0x32 => '2'
'1' => 0x31 => 00110001 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'0' => 0x30 => 00110000 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'0' => 0x30 => 00110000 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'0' => 0x30 => 00110000 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'0' => 0x30 => 00110000 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'0' => 0x30 => 00110000 => 0011000 + (parity bit 1) => 00110001 => 0x31 => '1'
'A' => 0x41 => 01000001 => 0100000 + (parity bit 0) => 01000000 => 0x40 => '@'
```